# tap into a websocket and send and receive a message (poor mans api)

Tags: node.js, typescript, websocket

I have a situation where I have 12 rasperry pis. the parent pi establishes a websocket over a port 1129 (for illustration purposes only)

The children connect to this port and messages in a custom message object are sent between the group of pis.

I now have a requirement that says an external connection should be allowed to join the websocket pipeline and send a request to the parent Pi. It would be processed and return the expected data.

We are using Node.js

I don't even know where to begin to make this work.

Is it a matter of typing in the external IP address of the Parent Pi and adding the port number and sending a message using the existing pipeline...and write it so the parent knows this message type collects the data and returns it?

[image: rough diagram]

Comment: Is it possible to provide a diagram?

Comment: I did a quick diagram. All Pis use ssh. All Pis are connected bi-directionally to Port 1111. A remote computer should be able to connect to any parent Pi (by IP) to get a stats report (log info) back.